# How to pass the value from table to servlet on the click of radio button?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, radio-button

Below is my first table in my jsp page which is getting generated dynamically. This table will have multiple rows.

```
First column in the first row is `radio button`, and second column in the first row is `GenId`.
First column in the second row is `radio button`, and second column in the second row is `GenId` again.
...
```

Below is my same table code -

```
<p>First table</p>
<Table id="table1">
     <tr>
          <TD>
               <input type="radio" name="test" id="radioButton" onclick="this.form.submit()>
          </TD>
         <TD>
               <span id="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
          </TD>
           ... some other TD's
     </tr>
</Table>
```

Now what I am suppose to do is as soon as I click on the radio button then I need to use the `GenId` of that row to pass to the servlet. Meaning, if I am clicking first row `radio button`, then I need to pass `GenId value` in the second column in the First row only to servlet.

As soon as I click on the radio button, it is able to call servlet properly but whenever I am trying to retrieve the `GenId` value in the servlet I always get null.

This is how I am trying to retrieving the value of `GenId` in the servlet -

```
String genIdValue = request.getParameter("importantColumnData");
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing and how to get the value?

I am totally new to this and I have tried a lot but no luck so far.. Any example will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value as an hidden input field so it guarantee the value is send as parameter so:

```
         <TD>
               <span id="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
               <input type="hidden" value="${Data.getGenId().get(i)}" name="importantColumnData" />
         </TD>
```

With this change you can get the value with the code `request.getParameter("importantColumnData");`